# Visa bulletin F4

Tags: usa, visa, family, application-status

I’m from Lebanon and my husband’s brother is a US Citizen. My priority date was 26 October 2010 and to date I haven't gotten a visa. Could you advise me on the processing times and when it is expected for NVC to start processing my case?

Comment: Which countries were you and your husband born in?

Answer (score 2):

You can see each month's visa bulletin [here](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/visa-law0/visa-bulletin.html). Assuming at least one of you or your husband was not born in India, Mexico, or the Philippines, visa numbers are currently available for F4 priority dates in 2006 (from the Final Action Date chart), and they are beginning to process cases for F4 priority dates in 2007 (from the Dates for Filing chart). Since your priority date is in 2010, you still have a few more years of wait for visa numbers.